# SSRS page break not applying PageName

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am creating a report with 3 tables in SSRS. Each table will be on it's own tab when exported out into Excel. I have applied the `PageBreak` property properly from what I can tell and applied the `PageName`.

Except when I export it out to Excel, it does the page breaks fine, but the names of the pages are still "sheet 1", "sheet 2", and "sheet 3".

I've had this work in the past and it is really confusing me now that it doesn't work, doing the same things as I've done in the past. Google doesn't help as it doesn't understand my question. I am hoping someone here could shed some light on the issue.

Edit: I just noticed it is giving me an error:

```
The PageName property specified on the data region, rectangle, or group 'Tablix2' was removed from the report.
SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services does not support the PageName property.
```

This is repeated 3 times for each of my tables. Which doesn't make sense, because in the same program I am adding page names to tabs when exported to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The `TargetServerVersion` in my project properties was set to `SQL Server 2008`. I had to change it to `SQL Server 2008 R2`.